# Seeking Core Data model design advice

Tags: ios, core-data, data-modeling

I have the following modeling problem in Core Data. A Student can take Lessons.
A Lesson has the following fields:

```
title
date
grade
type
```

A Lesson can be one of three types:

*lessontype1*:

```
subtype11 subtype12 subtype13
```

*lessontype2*:

```
subtype21 subtype22 subtype23 subtype24
```

*lessontype3*:

```
 subtype31 subtype32 subtype33 subtype34 subtype35
```

How do I set the `lesson.type` to any of these three types of Lessons? Is there a better way to model this scenario?

Comment: Are the types and subtypes classes? Or are they just some indicator? What else does depend on the type?

Comment: @Nick Weaver   Yes the lesson types are classes, subtypes are fields. If the lesson type changes the way they are displayed and added changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of your model depend on details of the data you are modeling.

If the types are just markers that have no logic or behavior associated with them, then the simplest model would be:

```
Student{
    lessons<-->>Lesson.student
}

Lesson{
    title:string
    date:date
    grade:number
    type:string
    subtype:string
    student<<-->Student.lessons
}
```

If the lessons have some kind of behavior associated with each type, then you could create subentities for each type of lesson.

```
Lesson{
    title:string
    date:date
    grade:number
    student<<-->Student.lessons
}

TypeOne:Lesson{

}

TypeOneSubOne:TypeOne{

}

// ...etc
```

Since all the Lesson subentities inherit from  Lesson, they can inherit the relationship as well. All the different subentities can be in the `Student.lesson` relationship.

If the types of lessons have behaviors associated with them, you can break them out into separate entities as well.

```
Lesson{
    title:string
    date:date
    grade:number
    type<<-->Type.lessons
    student<<-->Student.lessons
}

Type{
    lessons<-->>Lesson.type
}

TypeOne:Type{

}

TypeOneSubOne:TypeOne{

}
```

A Core Data model is intended to simulate real-world objects, events or conditions and the relationships between them. The first step in designing a model is to understand those real-world things and the relationships between them.

Comment: I think the third solution is the most elegant solution. But I will go with the first one, due to its simple nature and low overhead of classes.